# Why isn't my PHP installation recognized by Apache on Windows XP?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, installation

I have done the procedure below given in http://www.ricocheting.com/server/php.html for installing PHP and Apache. When I start the Apache server, it is displaying "invalid command PHPIniDir". How can I fix this problem?

I wanted to learn PHP. When I started installing I came with this problem.

> Editing Apache Conf File
>
> Using Notepad open httpd.conf (should be start-menu shortcut "Apache HTTP Server 2.2 > Configure Apache Server > Edit the Apache httpd.conf Configuration File"). Either at the very beginning or end of the file add the following lines: (NOTE: be sure to change BOTH C:/php parts to the directory you installed PHP to)

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

Comment: Any reason why not on Linux OS? Will be much more easier.

Comment: I have only windows xp

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered installing an Apache distribution? I have found XAMPP to be very easy to set up and use: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend you using XAMPP. It is a complete package of Apache, PHP, MySQL and so on... You don't have to configure and you can easily stop the processes so that you don't have an open webserver running on your computer all the time which can be risky if accessible over the Internet.

Try: [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org)

Comment: what you don't like pain?

Comment: I tried upgrading xampp from 1.7.3 to 1.7.7 and everything broke. yay

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember having this problem as well. If I remember correctly you might need to add a trailing / to the PHPIniDir

```
PHPIniDir "C:/php/"
```

Answer (score 0):

The only other alternative that I know of to [XAMPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/) is to install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). I've used WAMP many times but I haven't tried XAMPP. They are full LAMP stacks (well WAMP stacks) that contain Apache, MySQL and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, drop the `PHPIniDir` command and place the php.ini in the same directory as the Apache.exe application.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new file called `php.conf`. In that file I placed the following:

> **php.conf**

```
Loadfile "C:\php\php5ts.dll"

LoadModule php5_module "C:\php\php5apache2_2.dll"

PHPIniDir "C:\php"

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Then I went to my `httpd.conf` file and included the `php.conf` file:

> **httpd.conf**

```
Include conf/extra/php.conf
```

I included the line above, right before these lines in my `httpd.conf` file, where all the other include lines are.

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when you copy and paste from webpages on the web, i had to change the quote 
marks to  "C:/PHP72" (straight)  from  “C:/PHP72” (curly) to get the service to restart in windows.

Like most web page they are sensitive to the littlest of differences.